# Unable to receive values from <option> tag in JSP page to getParameter function in servlet page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In `countrylogin.jsp`

I am trying to fetch an integer value from a database in `<option value=<%rs.getInt(1);%>>`

and send it to a servlet page `countrylogin.java`

```jsp
<tr><th>COUNTRY LIST:</th>
             <th><select name="sel3" >
        <option>--SELECT--</option>
  <% while(rs.next())
    {  %>

    <option value=<%rs.getInt(1);%>> <% out.println(rs.getString(2)); %></option>
       <% } %>
        </select></th></tr>
```

In countrylogin.java:

I am trying to receive the option selected in the last page using getParameter() method, but I am not able to receive the values!

```
Connection con=conn.connectionprovider.getDbConnection();
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from country");
int select=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sel3"));
System.out.println(select);
String username=request.getParameter("t1");
String password=request.getParameter("t2");
DateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date fromdate=new Date();
System.out.println(dateformat.format(fromdate));
int s=st.executeUpdate("insert into   " +              
    "countrylogin(cid,username,password,fromdate,status) " +      
    "values("+select+",'"+username+"','"+password+"', "+
    ""+dateformat.format(fromdate)+"','active')");
System.out.println("work...");
request.getRequestDispatcher("addcountrylogin.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but it seems that instead of

```
<option value=<%rs.getInt(1);%>>
```

you should used

```
<option value="<%= rs.getInt(1) %>">
```

to actually print to HTML value from database. Without it your options would look like

```
<option value=>foo</option>
<option value=>bar</option>
```

instead of

```
<option value="42">foo</option>
<option value="24">bar</option>
```

so its value would be based on its content which means that in first case values would be `foo` and `bar` instead of `42` and `24` which would cause exception in

```
int select=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sel3"));
```

---

Also instead of

```
<% out.println(rs.getString(2)); %>
```

you can write

```
<%= rs.getString(2) %>
```